# Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have created a simple project which uses babel and webpack. I have checked it in here

https://github.com/abhitechdojo/MovieLensReact.git

In my root folder I have two files script1.js and script2.js. My webpack.config.js looks like

```
module.exports = {
    entry : {
        main: [
            'script1.js', 'script2.js'
        ]
    },
    output : {
        filename: 'public/main.js'
    },
    "module" : {
        "loaders" : [
            {
                "test": /\.jsx?/,
                "exclude": /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }               
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but when I run webpack. it cannot find any javascript files

```
ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'script1.js' in /Users/abhishek.srivastava/MyProjects/MovieLensReact
 @ multi main

ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'script2.js' in /Users/abhishek.srivastava/MyProjects/MovieLensReact
 @ multi main
```

Comment: in nodejs I get problem with require() when I forget to prefix the js filenames with "./" in the path.  You should try `main: ['./script1.js', './script2.js']`

Comment: that worked. could you post this as an answer. this was so simple.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In nodejs, when you call `require("script1.js")` it won't search in the current folder.

You have to use `require("./script2.js")`, to specify that the file is in the current folder.

In your case, modify the config file with `main: ['./script1.js', './script2.js']`.

Comment: Oh, I wish I saw your answer two hours ago. Darn... +1 fr clarity. However, I'm not sure how the `main` fits into this whole thing. In my config I only have `entry: "index.js"` and nothing more. Should I add `main` as well?